# Multiple Identical Divs to only change url image

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new to web development and I'm trying to practice by making a small site for my mom!

So basically I have this div that I want to replicate multiple times only changing the image url & the h3 caption.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 mb-5 col-md-6">
     <div class="wine_v_1 text-center pb-4">
          <a class="thumbnail d-block mb-4"><img src="images/im.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
         <div>
             <h3 class="heading mb-1"><a href="#">Us</a></h3>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking of using JavaScript to copy the div as a string to be something like ( pseudocode )

```
for image.length {
    getelementbyid.print (div1 + imageArray(i) + div2 + caption(i) + endofDiv ) 
}
```

Would this be possible? Would it make sense to do it this way or is there a more simple way?

Answer (score 0):

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/hb6d01ve/47/)

The example works by having a `data` object, which stores the captions and image URLs. Then, there is a clone template. It loops through each and clones the template, and replaces each element with the correct content. Then it adds it to the HTML with `.appendChild`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function doing this job. Creating copies of your element and change the attributes corresponding to your new data.

```js
function copyAndChangeImageAndCaption(){

    const images = [
    {imageUrl: "images/de.jpg", caption: "De"},
    {imageUrl: "images/it.jpg", caption: "It"},
    {imageUrl: "images/fr.jpg", caption: "Fr"}
];

    images.forEach(image => {
        const el = document.getElementsByClassName('col-lg-4 mb-5 col-md-6');
        let copy = el[0].cloneNode(true)
        copy.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')[0].childNodes[0].src=image.imageUrl;
        copy.getElementsByClassName('heading')[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = image.caption;
        document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(copy);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-5 col-md-6">
        <div class="wine_v_1 text-center pb-4">
             <a class="thumbnail d-block mb-4"><img src="images/im.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></a>
            <div>
                <h3 class="heading mb-1"><a href="#">Us</a></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

<button onClick="copyAndChangeImageAndCaption()">Add images</button>
```